# How does one go about undoing an avformat_seek_file call in libavcodec?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

I have an application written around libavcodec that sometimes attempts to seek ahead in a video while performing some work. The call to `avformat_seek_file` can only seek to a keyframe, so sometimes I end up in a situation where it ends up seek backwards from my current position in the decoding routine causing me to have to repeat work. For example, if I'm on frame 150 and I want to seek to frame 200, but the only key frames in the file are on frames 1 and 100, this call will have me seek back to frame 100, meaning I now have to decode 100 frames to get to 200 instead o 50 frames to get to 200 from my original decoding position of frame 150.

Is there a way for me to tell avformat_seek_file to undo its last seek and reset me to my previous location? Is there some other way for me to "save" my decoding state to undo this wrongful seek manually?

edit - it should be noted that my videos are always h264 encoded in an mp4 container.

Comment: Good question and  I don't have the answer but just to make sure, "`avformat_seek_file` can only seek to a keyframe" is that a fact or assumption ?

Comment: I should have clarified, for H264-encoded streams it can only seek to keyframes but in other formats (that aren't delta-compressed) it is possible to seek to non-keyframes: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/group__lavf__decoding.html#gaa23f7619d8d4ea0857065d9979c75ac8